# Little League Baseball Question

Tags: baseball

Question on a game I watched: Ages 8-11

2 Outs, runner on 3rd and 1st. Coach wouldn't let the runner on 1st steal- Why not? It didn't make any sense to me; as it would have put 2 in scoring position and if the catcher had thrown to 2nd the 3rd baserunner could have scored? Seems like a fundamental to teach the players and it wasn't used.

Answer (score 2):

Stealing is often not allowed in Little League play.  I don't know of a freely available rulebook, but http://www.rutherford-ll.info/rules2.htm has a list of differences between Little League and MLB rules.

> Position of Runners at Time of Pitch
>
> - LL - Runner may not leave base before pitch reaches batter. If violation, no runner may advance farther than forced by batter’s
>     action. Exception under Note 15.
> - OBR - No rule

Also from there:

> By convention, the Little League rule is noted as “LL”, and the
>   Official Baseball Rule as “OBR”. Please note that these rules apply
>   strictly to the Major and Minor League levels of Little League
>   Baseball. Higher levels use rules more consistent with the Official
>   Rules.

Per [Little League](https://www.littleleague.org/play-little-league/baseball/divisions/), age 8-11 would be Major or below, so very likely covered by these rules.

Comment: "Coach wouldn't let the runner on 1st steal" makes it sound like stealing was an option, just one the *coach* wouldn't allow.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 outs so if you get one of the runners out during a steal then the inning is over. Even if both runners go at the same time and the runner on 3rd reaches home before the runner at 2nd is thrown out by the catcher the inning is over and the run doesn't count.

Comment: In MLB, steals are not force plays.